# ui-grid columnDefs : how to translate cell content to some value which is user-friendly and a function of the data?

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have this ==>

```
$scope.uiGrid306 = {
    rowTemplate:rowtpl,
    columnDefs: [{
        field: '_ab_area', name: 'Area', width: "7%"
        , filter: { type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT, selectOptions: AREAS } 
        }, { ...

        }, {
        field: '_ab_x_style', name: 'Groups', width: "5%"
        , filter: { type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT, selectOptions: RISKS, condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT
        } 
    } 
    ]//columnDefs
    , enableFiltering: true
};//-->gridOptions
```

But my _ab_x_style has the data which is not user-friendly as I have wanted them to be.  So I need a function to return a translation of those data to user-friendly words.  The problem is HOW???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that purpose, you need to apply a [cellFilter](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef) to the cell content.  And a translate function to drop down options which also has those non-userfriendly data.

cellFilter is a filter to apply to the content of each cell.

```
$scope.uiGrid306 = {
    rowTemplate:rowtpl,
    columnDefs: [{
        field: '_ab_area', name: 'Area', width: "7%"
        , filter: { type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT, selectOptions: AREAS } 
        }, { ...

        }, {
        field: '_ab_x_style', name: 'Groups', width: "5%", cellFilter: 'TranslateMe'
        , filter: { type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT, selectOptions: RISKS, condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT
        } 
    } 
    ]//columnDefs
    , enableFiltering: true
};//-->gridOptions
```

Right after your angular controller, you implement that filter by

```
Yours.controller('BodyController', function($scope, $http, $filter, uiGridConstants, $timeout, $resource) {

})
.filter( 'TranslateMe', function (){
    return(function(value){
        return((value=='dataExcep'?'red':(value=='dataExcepLblueNoVal'?'blue':(value=='dataExcepYellowRevHi'?'yellow':(value=='dataExcepNew'?'aqua':'neutral')))));
    });
});
```

Then, for your drop-down options, you also have to apply a function

```
function TranslateMe(value){
    return((value=='dataExcep'?'red':(value=='dataExcepLblueNoVal'?'blue':(value=='dataExcepYellowRevHi'?'yellow':'neutral'))));
}
```

for your options building as such

```
function loadOptions( $scope, serverdata ){

    _.forEach( _.sortBy( _.uniq( _.pluck( serverdata, '_ab_x_style' ))  ), function ( eachOpt )    {
        RISKS.push( { value: eachOpt, label: TranslateMe(eachOpt) } )
    } );
    $scope.uiGrid306.columnDefs[10].filter.selectOptions = RISKS;
}
```

Result (instead of user unfriendly data, I have the names of the colors) --

[image: Make User-friendly Data]